# Deriving an expression from Navier-Stokes under creeping flow

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, navier-stokes

So I'm trying to derive
$$\mu\nabla^2\vec{v}=\nabla P-\rho g$$
from Navier-Stokes equation
$$\begin{align}\rho \left(\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}+\vec{v}\cdot(\nabla\vec{v})\right)&=\rho\vec{g}-\nabla P+\mu\nabla^2\vec{v}\\
\rho \left(\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}+\vec{v}\cdot(\nabla\vec{v})\right)-\mu\nabla^2\vec{v}&=\rho\vec{g}-\nabla P
\end{align}$$

under creeping flow.

I began with looking at the left-hand side of Navier-Stokes equation, which I expanded to:

$$\rho \left(\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}+v_x\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial x}+v_y\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial y}+v_z\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial z}\right)-\mu\left(\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial z^2} \right)$$

Because of the creeping flow I know that $v_x\approx v_y\approx v_z\approx0$. Because of this I can therefore write the left-hand side as:

$$\rho \frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}-\mu\left(\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial^2\vec{v}}{\partial z^2} \right)$$

But from here I am stuck. I asked a friend who said that since $v_x\approx v_y\approx v_z\approx0$ we can also remove the $\frac{\partial\vec{v}}{\partial t}$-term but I find this mathematically incorrect since the derivate of a function isn't necessarily small just because the function is small. As an example the function
$$\vec{v}(t)=((t+1000)^2-10^6)\vec{e_x}+((t+100)^3-10^6)\vec{e_y}+((t+50)^2-2500)\vec{e_z}$$ is small when $t=0$ but that isn't true for the derivate in $t=0$.
Is it something I'm missing when it comes to creeping flow? Is it that $v_x$, $v_y$ and $v_z$ are constantly small and therefore we can se them as constant functions and therefore the derivate is also neglectable?

Comment: The equation you are trying to derive is the stationary form of the Navier-Stokes equation under the assumption of Creeping flow. For stationary flows, the time derivative vanishes, i.e. $\partial_t\vec{v}\rightarrow 0$